# Scroll to reveal content jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in need a cross-browser jQuery solution for revealing elements on a HTML page with jQuery, the elements are loaded on page load, however i want to have the ability to scroll the page to "fadein" elements.

Is there an existing plugin with this functionality ?

**NOTE**: loading of the data is not required, and google has failed me thus far.

Comment: you think about something like this? http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/ edit: or this http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Comment: [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(document).height() - $(window).height() < 20)
      {
         var content = 'hi'; //you can use a AJAX call to get content
         $('#DivToAppendContentTo').append('content');

      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past. Read over and see if it works for you. There is a Demo at the bottom and you'll need to modify the code slightly to add your fade in. Be sure to give your element a CSS style of Hidden so that it is first not seen on the page. The jQuery fade in function will take display it.

Ariel Flesler's ScrollTo:
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, a plugin can do that easily!

http://scrollrevealjs.org/