# Trigger image display with CSS3

Tags: html, css, animation

i am kind of a noob with css3 transition, i would like to trigger an image on scroll position (or when visible) with a css3 animation from opacity:O to 1. I have a great example here : http://bonvalletromain.com/projects/citroen-creative-awards

I want to do the same with the images and trigger them on scroll position.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to use some sort of javascript to trigger the events.  Here's a simple solution that uses jQuery to listen to the scroll event on the window:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(document).height() - $(window).height() < 20)
  {        
     $('#DivWithImage').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

(The above based on [Scroll to reveal content jQuery Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544996/scroll-to-reveal-content-jquery-plugin)).

You could modify the above to append a class to the div, as shown here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-transitions-javascript/

and therefore do the animation using css3, but if you're already using jQuery, why bother?

Comment: Great thank you it works fine but how do i do to make it stay displayed ? When I scroll back up or if i continue scrolling down it disappears again

Comment: You could just check if the element is currently hidden:
**if(!$('#DivWithImage').is(":visible") { ... }**